# Printing an array within a specific range

Tags: c++, c++14

I was writing a program that says to:
Read in 20 numbers from the keyboard, each of which must be between 10 and 100 inclusive. If the user inputs any number outside of the expected range, you must repeatedly ask for a new value until it is acceptable. As each number is read, print it only if it is not a duplicate of a number already read. Please note that the same number can be input 20 times as long as it is within the proper range. However, if that were to happen, the number would only be printed once because the others are duplicates.
The part I had trouble with was printing a number only once if many of itself were inputted(within the range of course).
This is what I have so far:

## include

```
int main()
{
    int SIZE{20};
    int myArray[SIZE]{0};

    for(int i{0}; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        while((myArray[i] < 10) || (myArray[i] > 100))
        {
            std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
            std::cin >> myArray[i];

            if(myArray[i] == myArray[i - 1])
            {
                std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
                std::cin >> myArray[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i{0}; i < SIZE; ++i)
        std::cout << myArray[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - your duplicate check is only comparing `myArray[i]` and `myArray[i - 1]` (so it'll only notice consecutive duplicates). You need to compare `myArray[i]` with everything from `myArray[0]` to `myArray[i - 1]`. But there are other issues, so I've written out how I would go about solving this problem from scratch.

Let's analyze the problem a bit more so we can identify what exactly the solution should include. There are 3 main pieces to this problem:

1. Let the user enter 20 numbers
2. The numbers must be between 10 and 100 (inclusive). If they enter an invalid number, don't reduce their remaining numbers
3. When they have 0 numbers remaining, print all unique numbers entered.

First off - we're repeating the input process until they've entered 20 numbers. That sounds like a loop.

```
const int SIZE = 20;
int myArray[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
    std::cin >> myArray[i];
}
```

Secondly, the number has to be between 10 and 100 (inclusive). So we only increment the index if their input was valid. Hmm, right now we've got a for loop which increments on every iteration. Let's change that to a while loop, and only increment if their input was valid.

```
const int SIZE = 20;
int myArray[SIZE];
while (i < SIZE)
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
    std::cin >> myArray[i];
    if (myArray[i] >= 10 && myArray[i] <= 100)
        ++i;
}
```

Next up - when they run out of numbers, print all the unique numbers. Here's my solution to that:

```
const int SIZE = 20;
int myArray[SIZE];
bool repeat = false;
int i = 0; //# of valid numbers entered so far
int j = 0; //array index
while (i < SIZE)
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
    std::cin >> myArray[j];
    //if the number was valid
    if (myArray[j] >= 10 && myArray[j] <= 100)
    {
        //check if it was unique.
        repeat = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
        {
            if (myArray[k] == myArray[j])
            {
                repeat = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //if the number was unique, increment the array index
        if (!repeat)
            ++j;
        ++i;
    }
}

//finally, print out every number in the array
for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
    std::cout << myArray[k] << std::endl;
```

We track the remaining entries (`i`) and the array index (`j`) separately. If their input was valid, increment `i`. Then check if that input was valid by looping through indices `0` to `j - 1`. If we find a duplicate, set the `repeat` flag to true and break out of the loop. Once we've checked every entry, if `repeat` is still false, it's a unique value; increment `j`. When they've run out of entries, output everything from `myArray[0]` to `myArray[j - 1]`.

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting a couple of typoes in the code you posted and also making some (questionable) other format edits. I hope you don't mind. Please note the code in this snippets doesn't check if `std::cin` actually succeeded.

Comment: Much appreciated, all that code formatting must've tripped me up a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It helped me a lot. I recently got into programming and ive been doing a lot of quizzes to help improve my skills. I now see that it is easier to break down the problem like you just did.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to create a set with all the values of your array and then to print only the values of the set. The `std::set` object will only keep one unique instance per value as it is designed to do so.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {

  int SIZE{20};
  int myArray[SIZE]{0};

  for(int i{0}; i < SIZE; ++i)
  {
      while((myArray[i] < 10) || (myArray[i] > 100))
      {
          std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
          std::cin >> myArray[i];

          if(myArray[i] == myArray[i - 1])
          {
              std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
              std::cin >> myArray[i];
          }
      }
  }

  // Set declaration
  std::set<int> uniqueValues;
  for(int i{0}; i < SIZE; ++i)
      uniqueValues.insert(myArray[i]);

  // Printing set values
  for(auto itr = uniqueValues.begin(); itr != uniqueValues.end(); ++itr)
      std::cout << *itr << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a really advanced answer for me. I just started learning to code and I really want to continue progressing. Is there a simpler method that can be implemented?